# Как сделать в локальной сети скрипт погоды?

Tags: php

Добрый день, на моем районе есть провайдер с большой сетью (Примерно 4000), на сайт можно зайти без подключения к интернету. И мало кто заходит на сайт с подключением к интернету. Сам сервер подключен к интернету.

**Суть вопроса:** как сделать скрипт погоды, которая будет обновляться только через сервер.
Дополнительная информация: Мой город Кривой Рог(Украина).

Comment: А она может обновляться как-то еще?

Comment: Обновляться пусть будет через сервер, но не через юзеров.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pageContent = file_get_contents($url); // $url - адрес страницы с погодой
```

А дальше по вкусу - регулярками, по ДОМу, как угодно разобрать код страницы, выдрать погоду, показать

Comment: Поподробнее можно, пожалуйста.

Comment: Все дальнейшее зависит от конкретной задачи, структуры страницы.
В переменной $pageContent сохраняется html код страницы с погодой.
А дальше ищется в коде блок. Например, если блок с погодой имеет id='weather', регулярное выражение - найти строку, которая находится между "id='weather' потом могут идти разные символы, а может не быть, затем символ >(закрытие тега)" и "<\/div>"

/id='weather'.*?>(.*?)<\\\/div>/

Comment: Сделал))) Нашел то что искал file_put_contents - для сохранения файла на сервер